# ubuntu 15.10 LaTex autocomplete not working

Tags: autocomplete, latex, ubuntu-15.10

After updating to Ubuntu 15.10 auto-complete in Latexila and Geany (with latex plugin only) doesn't show completion suggestions. I've also tried other latex editor with the same result.

Note that Geany shows auto-completion correctly with other programming language. Also I'm using GTK+ and Xfce environment.

Does anyone have any idea on what's causing this? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have this in .bashrc

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```